# How to convert 86401 Seconds to 24:00:01 in powerBI Desktop October2023 version?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a SQL query output in a column labeled as **'LossinHours'** but the data is in seconds. for Eg. where my **'LossinHours'** is 1 hour it gives me 3600 (60 seconds x 60 minutes).

I want to use this column to show me the total **'LossinHours'** but in the [hh]:mm:ss (as it is in ms excel) format and that also in more than 24 hrs format. for eg. When my **'LossinHours'** is 24hrs and 1 Second - it is currently giving me data in seconds as 86401. I want to show the output on a card visual as 24:00:01.

so on and so forth assuming that the **'LossinHours'** for a particular day is 336 hours - I currently get out as 1209600 seconds - this should show me in power bi Card Visual as 336:00:00.

in another example my **'LossinHours'** for month is 22141 Hours it's giving me 79707600 secs - it should show me a total loss of 22141:00:00 Hrs

Can someone please help me here?

Thanks in advance,
Yogesh D. Khebde

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZMRH.png)

in the above example its showing me a loss of 13:06:00 for 79707960 secs data - which is actually [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAmno.png).

the column formula I have used is as given ahead: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQUXX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to write this out yourself. Try:

```
LLHours =
VAR _secs =
    SUM ( Shrinkage[LateArrival] )
VAR _hrs =
    INT ( _secs / 3600 )
VAR _mins =
    INT ( ( _secs - ( _hrs * 3600 ) ) / 60 )
VAR _sec = _secs - ( _hrs * 3600 ) - ( _mins * 60 )
RETURN
    FORMAT ( _hrs, "0" ) & ":"
        & FORMAT ( _mins, "00" ) & ":"
        & FORMAT ( _sec, "00" )
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne @Marcus you have given a precise answer to my question. i will definitely try both the solutions and share my views on them.

Answer (score 0):

I belive your are looking for a Time Duration type of value, but that's not currently supported by [Power BI](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Duration-format/m-p/447543). A workaround may be to get the seconds into a HH:MM:SS kind of string.

```
SplitSeconds = 
    VAR seconds = CALCULATE(MAX(TABLE[ORIGINALSECONDS]),ALLEXCEPT(TABLE,TABLE[SOMECOLUMNTOFILTER]))
    VAR hours = INT(seconds/3600)
    VAR minutes = INT((seconds - hours*3600)/60)
    VAR remseconds = INT(seconds - hours*3600 - minutes*60)
    RETURN CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(hours,":"),minutes),":"),remseconds)
```

Basically, convert the original seconds to hours by dividing by 3600. Subtract the obtained hours times 3600 from the original seconds, then divide the result by 60 to get the minutes. Calculate the remaining seconds by subtracting the hours times 3600 and the minutes times 60 from the original seconds.

Comment: in the first place - Thanks for replying ... and revealing the fact to me that POWER BI doesn't support this format yet. and next on - thanks a bunch for the workaround - hope it works as I desire. I'll definitely try it out and share my update whether it works or not. also just wanted to check if 'ORIGINALSECONDS' refers to the 'LossinHours' column in my question.

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, 'ORIGINALSECONDS' is any column where you have the untransformed seconds, in your case 'LossinHours'.

 Also, for easier data handling I would recommend you creating multiple columns for each value, i.e. one column for the hours, one for the minutes and one for the seconds, this way will make easier to acces any of this values individually.

Comment: Cant agree less on it... thanks for added valueable input @PC_User